# Where can I find the API for the Postfix mailbox_command

Tags: postfix

I'd like to create a custom program for handling incoming mail from postfix.  I'd like to hook this into postfix by making it the [mailbox_command](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mailbox_command).  The manual indicates that there are a number of environment variables which are set when this command is invoked, however it doesn't say much else and doesn't include any particular requirements of this command.

Specifically I'd like to know:

1. how (if at all) the return code is used by postfix (what are the expected return codes and what effect do they have).
2. The mail itself appears to be handed to the command by passing it into the stdin.  Is this a pipe or a temp file or is this not defined? The difference this makes is that a temp file can be memory mapped where as a pipe needs to be read byte by byte.
3. Can this command deffer accepting a mail (effectively tell postfix to try again later) - this could be answered by (1).
4. Is the stdout / std error logged or otherwise used in any way?

Does anyone know where this information can be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, the postfix documentation is complete in describing its behaviour.

From [**local(8)**](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html):

> Mailbox delivery can be delegated to an  external  command
>          specified  with  the mailbox_command_maps and mailbox_com-
>          mand configuration parameters. The command  executes  with
>          the  privileges  of  the  recipient user (exceptions: sec-
>          ondary groups are not enabled;  in  case  of  delivery  as
>          root,   the   command  executes  with  the  privileges  of
>          default_privs).

If mailbox_command is set, local(8) behaves as it does under the next section, EXTERNAL COMMAND DELIVERY.

A mailbox_command is, obviously, an external command.

BTW the manual page you link to contains examples referring to, for one, procmail(1). This should provide a big hint on how mail is delivered to the command.

Comment: Ah I hadn't found that the manual page for `local` contains this.  Thanks very much.